# Which is more reliable for Github API Conditional Requests, ETag or Last-Modified?

Tags: github-api, etag, last-modified

The [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests) specifies two headers that can be used in Conditional Requests, `Last-Modified` and `ETag`. Which is the more reliable when querying the API?

For context: when using the api endpoint  [`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees/:sha`](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree) on each subdir of a large repo, every response contains the same `last-modified` value (even though the repo on github shows different authored dates) while the `etag` value for each is different. I'm wondering if the `ETag` is a more granular representation of repo content state change (for caching purposes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading "[ETags: a pretty sweet feature of HTTP 1.1](https://gist.github.com/6a68/4971859)", it says:

> "[ETags allow dynamic content to be cached using an app-specific "opaque token"](https://gist.github.com/6a68/4971859#etags-allow-dynamic-content-to-be-cached-using-an-app-specific-opaque-token)"
>
> An ETag, or entity tag, is an opaque token that identifies a version of the component served by a particular URL. The token can be anything enclosed in quotes; often it's an md5 hash of the content, or the content's VCS version number.

If the content of the answer is the same, the ETag should be identical everytime.

I just tested it with https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/gopanic/git/trees/master, and indeed its ETag remains `W/"34a03ea1d4dc0b5d533ecf8d36492879"` even when called repeatedly.

But should I get the tree for each subfolder, then the ETag would vary because it represents a signature of the different response content.

The advantage of ETag is that it doesn't depend on a date (whose clock might vary for diverse reason), but on the content of the answer: if unchanged, it

---

Warning: [Brice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48136/brice) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060116/which-is-more-reliable-for-github-api-conditional-requests-etag-or-last-modifie/28061854#comment131152766_28061854):

> The `etag` value is specific to the server, for example GitHub might use the hash of the blob, but maybe, not always.
> Other providers may not even do that, e.g. Apache was using the `inode` for `etags` in the past.

Comment: Thanks - appears that the `ETag` header reveals correct state change, while the `Last-Modified` header is relative to the entire repo (when using the github api).

Comment: I thought there was a bug because I was getting 304 every time on get reference, even when there were new commits. Updating to use the etag instead of last-modified fixed the problem

Comment: In case `ETag` is used in combination with `Authorization` header sending a token, making a request with one token will respond 304 every time in case the document doesn't change, but if you send the same ETag but using a different token the endpoint will respond with a 200, doesn't matter if the document change or not. So is there a way to know if the document changed but without relaying in the token sent? Taking in account that `Last-Modified` header is not available (missing in response header) for all of the github api endpoints.

Comment: @p1nox I don't know, but that should be a good question on its own.

Comment: Side note, the etag value is specific to the server, for example github my use the hash of the blob, but maybe not always. Other providers may not even do that, e.g. Apache was using the inode for etags in the past.

Comment: @Brice Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, at least in its state on Aug 1, 2019, GitHub API's and for `/releases/latest` endpoint, `ETag` is not giving consistent values.

*Most* of the time it will give you consistent non-changing `ETag` value, but randomly (sometimes often) the `ETag` will be different. See my examples, I ran an API call couple times:

```
curl -IsL -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" https://api.github.com/repos/mautic/mautic/releases/latest | grep -P '^(HTTP/|ETag:|X-RateLimit-Remaining|Last-Mod)'
```

First result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 56
ETag: W/"b86f015c353e7c1d773f1f781d4cf822"
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Mar 2019 23:14:15 GMT
```

Some times later:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
ETag: W/"9f670edf97e04c5c23cce74457be61a3"
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Mar 2019 23:14:15 GMT
```

Note how `Last-Modified` stays intact, so doing conditional `GET` only using that header will result in better API cacheability in comparison to `ETag`.

Comment: This seems to be the case still today: https://twitter.com/CAFxX/status/1490560328261791746